# The number of spanning trees containing a certain edge $e$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ and edge $e = (v,w) \in E$.
I have to prove that the number of spanning trees of $G$ is equal to:
\begin{equation}
\det Q^{\{v,w\}}(G)
\end{equation}
Where $Q^{\{v,w\}}(G)$ is the Laplacian matrix of $G$ with the $v$'th and $w$'th rows and columns removed.
I know this is in fact a generalisation of the matrix-tree theorem, but I don't understand why I have to remove some extra rows and columns. If I remove -for example- the $v$'th column, I am left with a matrix that represents a graph with some loops, so I can't use the matrix-tree theorem again...

Could anybody help me out?